# How to match a precise number within a string with PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I've written a script to get port information on a single port. The script pipes 'netstat -anob' into a variable then uses Where-Object to scan the object for the exact port number and spit back the desired info.

Unfortunately, the only conditional parameter I use that gets a positive result is -match. But it also yields false positives.

```
$netstatport = $netstat | Where-Object { $_ -match $port }
```

If the port I'm searching for is, for example, 555, then the info is found. But the same info is also found if $port is equal to 55. In other words, what I need is:

$port = 55 >> False

$port = 555 >> True

$port = 5555 >> False

I've tried various conditions like -eq, -ieq, =, and so on. Only -match works, but it's too imprecise.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try `Where-Object {$_ -match "\b"+$port+"\b"}` or `Where-Object {$_ -match "\b$port\b"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\b` to match at word boundary:

```
$netstatport = $netstat | Where-Object { $_ -match "\b$port\b"}
```

This way, you will not match `555` or `5555` if you pass just `55`.

Comment: `"\b$port\b"` is sufficient, PowerShell will automatically expand the `$port` variable

Comment: It does, as long as you use [double quotes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx) :)

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html) are supported by the `-match` operator.

```
$port = 55
$regex= ":$port\s"
$netstat = Where-Object { $_ -match $regex}
```

Breaking down the regex:

- `:` - character representing the port delimiter in netstat output
- `$port` - variable containing the port number you specify
- `\s` - single white space after the port number

Note that this pattern will return values that match both local and foreign IP addresses/port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with taking parameter/user input and using it directly in a regular expression, because any special characters will be interpreted, and you can't predict which ones will be present.

Therefore you should escape it with `[RegEx]::Escape()`:

```powershell
$escPort = [RegEx]::Escape($port)
$netstat | Where-Object { $_ -match "\b$escPort\b" }
```

(This uses `\b` but it's the same principle if you want to use something more specific like the other answer)